# Why fingers in human fists get folded in absence of neural stimuli?

Tags: neuroscience, muscles

**Background:**

I noticed that the fingers in our fist tend to get folded in absence of neural stimuli. The same thing happens in case of our hands and legs.

**Question:**

1. What is the mechanism behind this phenomenon?
2. Is there any positive or negative outcome of this phenomenon?

Comment: https://www.reddit.com/r/explainlikeimfive/comments/2yupq3/eli5_why_do_our_fingers_naturally_curl_when_our/

Answer (score 1):

1. I would assume that as a result of the lengths of the tendons and the arrangements of the various flexor + extensor muscles, the slightly folded positions (curved) fingers, hands, legs, etc. are the "default" positions, in which both antagonistic muscles are in their relaxed state (thus without neural stimulation)
2. The evolutionary benefit of the slightly curved fingers, hands, legs, etc. may have been more relevant in our primate ancestors than it is today